# Unfolding JsonArray Response object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I am trying to unravel my response from a fetch:

```js
  fetch('restservices/users/', fetchOptions)
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log('1');
        console.log(response)
        const responseSjon = response.json()
        console.log('2');
        console.log(responseSjon);
        console.log('3');
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson, null, 2));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
        console.log('4');
```

In my Javascript I unpack the response as a json with response.json.
Then I console.log to my browser, and the (raw) response in the console is as such:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp5r3.png)

```json
[
   {
      "email":{
         "chars":"CasaSuCasa",
         "string":"CasaSuCasa",
         "valueType":"STRING"
      },
      "naam":{
         "chars":"Coyote",
         "string":"Coyote",
         "valueType":"STRING"
      },
      "hoeveelheid zoekopdrachten":{
         "integral":true,
         "valueType":"NUMBER"
      }
   },
   {
      "email":{
         "chars":"syd@barrett.com",
         "string":"syd@barrett.com",
         "valueType":"STRING"
      },
      "naam":{
         "chars":"CrazyDiamond",
         "string":"CrazyDiamond",
         "valueType":"STRING"
      },
      "hoeveelheid zoekopdrachten":{
         "integral":true,
         "valueType":"NUMBER"
      }
   }
]
```

Am I correct in saying that it looks to be an array containing JsonArray objects, containing json objects?

My question is how do I reach this objects individually in a console.log(xxx); ?

EDIT:
This is what the rest service on the other side, I have access to both:

```java
            Map<String, User> commune = Community.getUserMap();
            JsonArrayBuilder jab = Json.createArrayBuilder();

            JsonObjectBuilder job = Json.createObjectBuilder();
            commune.forEach((key, user) -> {

                job.add("email", user.getEmail());
                job.add("naam", user.getNaam());
                job.add("role", user.getRole());
                job.add("hoeveelheid zoekopdrachten", user.getAlleZoekertjes().size());
                jab.add(job);
            });
            return ok(jab.build()).build();
        }
```

Comment: It is an array of objects

Comment: Array containing Objects.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how do I reach those individual items? I added an image for clarity.

Comment: use fetch('restservices/users/', fetchOptions).then(response=>response.json()).then(response=>console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)))

Comment: Is that a typo `responseJson` and `responseSjon` ???

Comment: its an insider joke @angel.bonev .. here in NL a sjon is a certain kind of John ;)

Comment: @RyanReddy nice one , but `responseJson` is not defined so , call that John then `console.log(JSON.stringify(responseSjon));` LOL

Comment: yeah that def works @angel.bonev but any clue as to how I could access the individual objects at the deepest level? I realize my question originally did not entail this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

log object in a formatted way using JSON.stringify

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson, null, 2));
```

or in your specific case, use this:

```js
fetch('restservices/users/', fetchOptions)
.then(response=>response.json())
.then(response=>console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)))
```

Comment: Cheers, no luck yet though.. I added an image of the console in browser to clarify what exactly is happening

Comment: this second function, the one you also posted in the comments above, does print the entire Json. so thats cool, I only would also like to access the most intricate JsonObjects individually, so say from naam{string:"CrazyDiamond"} I would like to extract "CrazyDiamond" ultimately I would like to add them through DOM to a page one by one

Comment: Use es6 array methods like map, reduce, and find to get individual objets.